# Why aren't all points in a set limit points (by this definition)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

I am self-studying Real Analysis using S. Abbot's *Understanding Analysis* and am a bit confused with the definition of a limit point of a set on page 89. The definition is as follows:

> A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighbourhood $V_\epsilon(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ at some point other than $x$.

This confuses me a bit - doesn't this apply to all points in $A$? for example, if we defined some point arbitrary $a$ somewhere in the middle of the set, won't we be able to keep shrinking the size of the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood, and by archimedian property, always find a member of this $\epsilon$-neighbourhood that is a member of A but not $x$?

Can someone help me reconcile this? I am a bit confused. Also, the additional notion of isolated points make this even more confusing - perhaps someone could explain the differences as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Noted below are some examples of sets with no limit points.  Also important is that there are sets with limit points that don't lie inside the set.  e.g. $A = (0,1)$ has limit points of $0$ and $1$ though those points are not in the open interval.

Comment: The intuition is that $x$ is a a limit point of $A$ If $A$ has infinitely many points that get as close to $x$ as you like.  Note that $x$ itself need not be (and in important cases often isn’t) an element of $A$.  We define limit points by talking about neighborhoods instead of a notion of “closeness” to get a definition that generalizes to topologies that don’t depend on the notion of a metric or distance.  If $x \in A$ but $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, then $x$ is an isolated point of $A$.  That just means there’s “elbow room” around $x$ that is completely outside of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. For some reason I was under the notion that some set has only a few or a finite amount of limit points, but it seems to me now that in most cases with sets from $\mathbb{R}$ limit points exist in most places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you have missed the “other than $x$” part of the definition. Clearly, for instance $1$ is *not* a limit point of, say $\{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $A=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for the usual topology.

$0$ belongs to $A$ but is not a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

> This confuses me a bit - doesn't this apply to all points in A? for
> example, if we defined some point arbitrary a somewhere in the middle
> of the set, won't we be able to keep shrinking the size of the
> ϵ-neighbourhood, and by archimedian property, always find a member of
> this ϵ-neighbourhood that is a member of $A$ but not $x$?

No. Consider $\ A = [0,1]\cup \{ 2\}.\ $ For any $\ \varepsilon<1,\quad V_{\varepsilon}(2) = \{2\}.$